# How do I find out my SIM number?

Tags: sim-card

I have a Samsung Galaxy GT-I9000 and need to find out my 20 digit SIM number somehow.

I have been told that I should go to `Settings > General > About` to find it.

However, it isn't! Does anybody know where this information is stored?

Answer (score 18):

How about taking the SIM out and see the number printed  on its back side (the other side of the contact surface) or next to it? Just thought to say this just in case if you are not aware of!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In many versions of Android for Verizon networks (e.g. Nexus devices, Moto X, Moto G), you can find this by going to Settings -> About Phone -> Status -> and this is listed as ICCID.

Answer (score 1):

try the [Sim card Details App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidyou.simcardinfo&hl=en)  , this is the best. easy to copy the numbers you get.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the huge number of different models of Android phone and the wide range of different software versions, you may find that your handset doesn’t have the SIM number in the same place. In this case, you can use a 3rd party app to find your SIM information. Such as the [sim card info](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sim%20card%20info&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiDwoNc2ltIGNhcmQgaW5mb3oFGADAAQKKAQIIAQ%3D%3D%3AS%3AANO1ljKNz8A&hl=en) app. Hope it helps.

Comment: Link for the app and a brief description? Also see [how to answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

How about the old fashioned way? Either calling another phone with it and checking it via Caller ID or if that doesn't work,  call the Provider and ask for it via the SIM Serial?

On another note: Many Providers *forget* to configure the SIM Cards phone number onto the SIM Card. That is why you probably cannot see it in your menu.

If you find out what the number is and want to correct the problem for the future, check out [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/themes-apps/app-sim-changer-change-registered-sim-t2106490).

Comment: How does phoning another phone give you the sim card number?

Answer (score -2):

or you can dial `*1#` from your mobile number

Comment: Dialing `*1#` on my Samsung Galaxy S4 doesn't work.

Comment: Dialing `*1#` in my LG P500  resulted in a message `MSISDN:YYXXXXXXXXXX`, where YY is my country code and XXXXXXXXXX is my 10 digit mobile number.

Comment: Doesn't work on Nexus 4, Android 4.4.4, and one of Singapore's mobile provider.

Answer (score -3):

I think the best solution is [SIM Card Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rachunek.android.simcard).

Answer (score -4):

the best way actually is to dial *#06# on your Android phone and it will pop up.

Comment: Dialling *#06# shows the phone's [IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity) number (doesn't work on tablets which do not have GSM radio) and not SIM's number.